# Finding the right formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet set up and used by one of my contractors, there is certain data that I need pulled from it, ie: the number of people per craft. Said spreadsheet is used for contractors payroll and therefore lists each employee, each employee is colored differently per craft. What function can I use to get the total sum of each craft.

Comment: You can use the [`=SUM()` Function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/tipsandfaqs/f/sum_autosum.htm)

Comment: The SUMIFS function will add the value of cells where a specified condition is met elsewhere in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your description of your data, I recommend `=COUNTIFS()`.  See the example below of how you could use it.  If your data is setup fundamentally different, or you're doing more than counting employees, please post some samples.

[image: countifs]